# aligning views in a custom listview row

Tags: android, listview, layout, alignment

I have a custom listview row whose XML has one ImageView and three TextViews inside a LinearLayout.

I want to align the last two TextViews to the right.

Help is appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Couldn't you use a RelativeLayout inside your linear layout then setup your layout that way.  Look into layout_alignParent[Right|Left|Top|Bottom] for RelativeLayouts

Comment: Yes I have tried gravity and Layout Gravity and it does not seem to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem , and i solved it using RelativeLayout in my listView_row.xml